# Resize image dynamically with CSS

Tags: css

I'm reading news on this page mostly on my mobile device:

[link](http://link.com)

The big banner right of the logo is not scaling properly on the mobile device.
So when you resize the window and make it smaller everything is resizing except the banner.

Im learning php, css and just wondering how this could be solved. Ive checked also on stackoverflow and find something like:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */ }
```

I've tried this also in the dev. mode of google chrome but it desnt work.
Is this solvable with the provided data from the dev mode?

Code looks like:

```
<div style="position:relative; 
width:728px; height:90px; z-index:10; 
background-image: url(http://www.image.jpg);">
```

Comment: Your inline style is fixing the width and height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code, the banner is implemented as background image, not an `IMG` element. To make background image scaled so that it's entirely visible, use [`background-size: contain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size). So your user styles could be like this:

```
.site-header-banner > DIV {
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; // To disable repeating background image.
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: When adding this attributes to .site-header-banner I receive something like this when scaled: http://s10.postimg.org/gran6hxx5/scaling.png "Adding" height: auto !important; causing disappearing of the image at all...

Comment: Add `background-repeat: no-repeat;` to prevent repeating background image. `height: auto` is irrelevant for background images — the element itself is empty, so its auto height is of course zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as a background with the following properties:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-size: cover;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/alexndreazevedo/xe9tvkyr/

You can define a fixed size to DIV containing image background and change it by media query.